# Jahia 6.6 CMS - Write an own manager

Tags: java, content-management-system, jahia

i'm actually working with the Jahia 6.6 CMS. Jahia provides the user with different managers where you upload files, change existing content and so on. I would like to provide an manager of my own.

Unfortunally the documentation of Jahia 6.6 isn't really specific what steps are necessary to achieve this. As far as i found some material about it, you are supposed to define some spring beans. But that's it basically. Has anyone some experience with this topic?

Any help is appreciated.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look also on Jahia's web site in the documentation section, tabs "how-tos"
there is one how-to about customizing the Edit Mode UI, which is a good introduction to the subject
and you can find here a document (it's only a draft version, sorry it's really something done very quickly) that explains exactly how you can customize managers
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xpzo7qEOt241IBZAq1Wr75U4BKqTGXl6dug0dh0k_VM/edit
The document should be updated soon with a section on "how to declare your own manager"

Best regards
Feel free to participate on Jahia Forums also.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the draft with me. Beside reading the document, i checked out the source code from the jahia repository and learnt a lot from it. I'm looking forward for the update of the section.

Comment: I tried now to add a new action to the existing file manager of jahia 6.6. Unfortunally, it just gave me an exception, that my class is not included in the set of types which can be serialized and will therefore not be serialized for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by a manager exactly, if you're talking about adding components, there is a document on templating and module writing available here : http://www.jahia.com/cms/home/community/documentation/templating-and-integration-guide.html

If you're interesting in actually customizing the edit mode this is more tricky because you will indeed have to go into Spring configuration files. You can find more details about this here : http://www.jahia.com/community/documentation/jahiapedia-v6_6/uicomponents/uicomponents.html

Comment: Thank you, i see what i can get out of those files.